# Kibana: How to visualise based on two fields

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4, elastic-stack

I have imported weblogs into `Elasticsearch` via `Logstash`. This has completed successfully.

I have a field in the log file (`clientip`) that is always populated and another field that is sometimes populated (`trueclientip`). I want to aggregate based on the coalescing of the two; e.g. if `trueclientip` is not empty then use that otherwise use `clientip`.

How can I do this with the Visualisation in Kibana? Do I need to generate a scripted field or is there another approach?

Thanks.

Comment: If those fields are numbers then it might work, otherwise not so sure. The reason would be the need to use scripted fields which allow only number fields.

Comment: @andreistefan they are IP addresses so they are strings. e.g. 127.0.0.1

Comment: They are not strings ;-). IPs are stored as numbers internally.

Answer (score 0):

Define a scripted field that should have this formula: `doc['trueclientip'].value ? doc['trueclientip'].value : doc['clientip'].value` and use this in your aggregations.

But, there is a downside to this scripted fields functionality AND the `ip` type: it seems what you get back from the script is the number itself (which is logic because the scripted fields in Kibana 4 only use Lucene expressions as a language), not the string representation. IPs internally are actually `long` numbers in Lucene.

For example, `127.0.0.1` is represented internally as `2130706433`. And this is what you will see in Visualize.

Is not ideal, indeed, and it would be good to have a more advanced scripting language in scripted fields, but a [github issue already exists](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/3180).